# Launching special links from a selected or clicked cell in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Google sheets restricts which link types can be launched (https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093313?hl=en), but with google apps scripts I was hoping to build a workaround so that people can launch an internal app with relevant information (ie `App:123132`). `onSelectionChange` would seem to be an option (when the user selects the cell with the relevant link, open the app) but it's not an installable trigger, limiting what can be done (specifically, I can not launch a new page or try to redirect to a uri such as `App:34234`). The other triggers don't seem to provide the functionality to do this without polling, which doesn't seem to be the right way to do this. Is there any other way people are aware of to make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without polling there isn't another way to make this happen. As you already mentioned there aren't simple/installable triggers able to open a link.

By using Google Apps Script one option is to create a web app to show the content of the "special link".

Another option is to use a dialog/sidebar to use client-side code to open the "special link"

Comment: I looked into creating a dialog to do this - my understanding was that this isn't possible with simple triggers such as `onSelectionChange`. Is there is a way to launch such a dialog?

Comment: Use a button (image with a script funciton assigned to it) or a custom menu